# Seleccion desde varias tablas

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

Tengo esta consulta que funciona bien

```
 var rest = (from de in se.DeliveryConfiguration 
             join re in se.restaurant on de.Restaurantid equals re.RestaurantID 
             where (de.Position.Distance(geografi)/1000) < de.Distance 
             select re).ToList();
```

Ahora nesecito agregar la  tabla *priceitem* y de esta obtener `MIN(price)` donde `Price <> 0` y por supuesto siguiendo la relacion del id

Aquí las tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas trabajando con el entity framework, debes poder obtener los objetos de la consultarlos o setearlos al objeto principal, que por lo que veo es de, después de esto enviar un saveOrUpdate, por medio del entity framework, así evitas estar realizando consultas separadas, solo con consultar de, deberías ver en el objeto las relaciones que mantiene, esa es la ventaja de trabajar con un ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Podes agrear mas de un join y un group by en el cual en el caso de ser varias columnas las agrupas asi {pr.Col1, pr.Col2} este grupo tiene una propiedad Key, que es del tipo anonymo que create en el group by o si es una sola columna sera este mismo tipo, este grupo es una lista de elementos por lo que podes indicar min, max, sum y demas

```
var rest = (from de in se.DeliveryConfiguration 
         join re in se.restaurant on de.Restaurantid equals re.RestaurantID 
         join pr in priceitem on  re.ItemID equals pr.itemid
         where (de.Position.Distance(geografi)/1000) < de.Distance &&
                pr.price !=0
         group pr by p.itemid into prGrupo     
         select new {re, minPrice = prGrupo.Min(t=> t.price)    ).ToList();
```